# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{c_n}$ necessarily diverge? Justify.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{a_n}$ is convergent and the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{b_n}$ is divergent. Let $c_{2n-1}$ = $a_n$ and $c_{2n}$ = $b_n$.

Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{c_n}$ necessarily diverge? Justify.

Hint: Let $R_n$ = $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{a_n}$ , $S_n$ = $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{b_n}$ , and $T_n$ = $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{c_n}$. Then $T_{2n}$ = $R_n$ + $S_n$. Is $T_{2n}$ convergent?

How to link the hint to the question?

Please help me check if my proof is correct:

Since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{a_n}$ is convergent, $R_n$ = $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{a_n}$ is also convergent.

Since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{b_n}$ is divergent, $S_n$ = $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{b_n}$ is also divergent.

Proof (by contradiction):

Assume that $T_{2n}$ = $R_{n}$ + $S_{n}$ (by hint) is convergent.

Since $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(-1){a_n}$ = -$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{a_n}$  converges,
  -$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{a_n}$ + $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{a_n+b_n}$ = $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{b_n}$

This implies that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{b_n}$ converges.
Thus, there exists a contradiction since $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{b_n}$ diverges.

This implies that $T_{2n}$ is divergent.

Therefore, $T_{n}$ diverges, which implies that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty{c_n}$ diverges.

Comment: In your hint, should the indices in the sums be $k$ instead of $n$?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Your proof is a little hard to follow, but otherwise, it looks correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets define 
$$R_n= \sum_{k=0}^n a_n \qquad S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n b_n \qquad T_n = \sum_{k=0}^n c_n$$
As
$$T_{2n}=R_n + S_n$$ 
we know that 
$$T_{2n}-R_n=S_n$$
If $T_{2n}$ is convergent, we would have convergent minus convergent equals divergent, which is impossible, hence $T_{2n}$ is divergent and hence $T_n$ is divergent.

Comment: thanks. could u help me check if my above ans is correct?

Comment: your answer is hard to unterstand, try to rephrase it

Comment: ok, i've tried to rephrase. so sorry about that.

Comment: @LeongLyn, you came here to learn. I believe you learnt something, there is nothing to be sorry about.

Comment: @LeongLyn you should really mention somewhere, that you assume $T_{2n}$ to be convergent, and that sum of convergent series is convergent, and as vonbrand said really no reason to be sorry

Comment: ok haha, er..is the proof correct? because i'm a year 1 student so there's bound to have errors in the working.

Comment: Correct is a big word, the idea is right, but some steps should be more explicit, robjohn updatet his answer look how he is doing and what you are saying. It is hard to write a proof, don't give up :) if you like come to the chat there i can explain it more explicit

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** consider the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(c_{2n-1}+c_{2n})
$$
**More:**
$$
\begin{align}
T_{2n}
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(c_{2k-1}+c_{2k})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k+b_k)\\
&=R_n+S_n
\end{align}
$$
Assume that $T_n$ converges; then $T_{2n}$ also converges (any subsequence of a convergent sequence converges). Thus, $S_n=T_{2n}-R_n$ is convergent (the difference of two convergent sequences is convergent). However, $S_n$ does not converge, therefore, our assumption is false. That is, $T_n$ is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Can $T_{2n}$ be convergent?

Assume it is so. Then, since $R_n$ is also convergent we have $T_{2n}-R_n = S_n$ is also convergent. Which means $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{b_n}$ is convergent. This is a contradiction.

Therefore $T_{2n}$ is divergent. Hence, $T_{n}$ is divergent. Which means $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty{c_n}$ is divergent.